# Raspberry PI 3 port forwarding issue

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I'm trying to port forward from PI to my local laptop :

```
~/tmp$ ssh -R "192.168.0.12:8000:localhost:8000" pi@192.168.0.12
pi:~/tmp$ netstat -an|grep 8000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:8000                :::*                    LISTEN     
pi:~/tmp$
```

Why it's listening on 127.0.0.1:8000, instead of 192.168.0.12:8000 ?

Comment: Did you enable GatewayPorts on your sshd server? as per man page ... `Specifying a remote bind_address will only succeed if the server's GatewayPorts option is enabled`

Answer (score 0):

It has done exactly what you told it to do with the localhost, that being 127.0.0.1 on yours and ever computer like a Mac, Windows, BSD, the list goes on I would think, Android...

Comment: JaromandaX has got right answer.